# Loop password in Python

Tags: python

The xls has password protection with particular one password.
Example: 'Thb0102','thB0102','tHb0102'.
So I decided to use msoffcrypto & io to decrypt the flie.
But it does not work.
I want to input password in loop until the file has been decrypted and read excel.
Then, I can process the dataframe (pandas).
Please help me!!
Thank you so much.

```
decrypted = io.BytesIO()
with open(a,'rb') as f:
    file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(f)
    while True:
        pw=input('Entre password ')
        if True:
            file.decrypt(decrypted)
            df = pd.read_excel(decrypted)
            try:
                file.load_key(password=pw)
                print('The flie has been decrpyted.')
                break
            except KeyError:
                print('Invaild Password.')
                continue
```

Comment: What does not work? Do you actually know the password?

Comment: I just know the pattern of password. There are too many users. They always change password.

Answer (score -1):

```
decrypted = io.BytesIO()

with open(a, 'rb') as f:
    file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(f)

    while True:
        pw = input('Enter password: ')
        try:
            file.load_key(password=pw)
            file.decrypt(decrypted)
            df = pd.read_excel(decrypted)
            print('The file has been decrypted.')
            break
        except msoffcrypto.exceptions.InvalidKeyError:
            print('Invalid password. Please try again.')
```

I think this one should help for you.

Comment: I change except KeyError to be except msoffcrypto.exceptions.InvalidKeyError: It works now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

I beleive you are trying to bruteforce the password.

In that case your logic is almost correct, just remove unecessary if and call the function to use your pandas dataframe.

```py
decrypted = io.BytesIO()
with open(a, 'rb') as f:
    file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(f)
    while True:
        pw = input('Enter password: ')
        try:
            file.load_key(password=pw)
            file.decrypt(decrypted)
            df = pd.read_excel(decrypted)
            print('The file has been decrypted.')
            # Call your function to process the dataframe here.
            # process_df(df)
            break
        except msoffcrypto.exceptions.InvalidKeyError:
            print('Invalid password. Please try again.')
            continue
```

I hope it makes sense.

EDIT:

Changed Exeption handeling to catch `msoffcrypto.exceptions.InvalidKeyError`

Comment: It still not working when I type wrong password for looping.

The Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\TestingRSA\TestingRSA.py", line 30, in <module>
    file.load_key(password=pw)
  File "C:\Users\sandy.tong\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\msoffcrypto\format\xls97.py", line 534, in load_key
    raise exceptions.InvalidKeyError("Failed to verify password")
msoffcrypto.exceptions.InvalidKeyError: Failed to verify password

Comment: It still does not working on looping in password when I type wrong password. But I change except KeyError to be except msoffcrypto.exceptions.InvalidKeyError: It works now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help. Let me edit the answer.